# Regex match string or empty

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

The strings:

```
1. {@IF var=val}
2. {@IF var}
```

My current pattern:

```
/{@if ([\w]+)(?:|=([\w]+))}/si
```

Groups that I need (2)

```
1. {@IF (var)=(val)}
2. {@IF (var)}
```

I have already done the #2 using this regex

```
/{@if ([\w]+)}/si
```

How can I match both #1 and #2 strings using a single regex pattern and produce one/two capture groups?

a 'g' modifier is needed.
but after I added a 'g' modifier in php it threw an unknown modifier error

http://regexr.com?31uov

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
/@IF (\w+)(?:=(\w+))?/
```

catpure-group 1 is the "variable name", capture-group 2 is optional (and maybe not set) with the value.